# An issue of a SPAM filter with Naive Bayes Classification in python

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, naivebayes

I'm trying to write a SPAM filter with Naive Bayes Classification program in python(3.6). My code has four parts as showed below:

1. Import same necessaire package, import the tranning dataset and test dataset and then use the sparse command to transfer the datasets to the format that I can handle with better
2. Define the trainning function function
3. Define the testfunction
4. Call the two function

For the first three parts of code, it can be runned in the jupyter notebook very well, but I am stuck in the execution of the test function

### first part code

```
#import the packages
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import sparse
from scipy import stats

#transfer the trainning dataset
data = pd.read_csv("emails-train-features.txt",' ',header=None)
mailLabel = pd.read_csv("emails-train-labels.txt",' ',header=None)
mailLabel.columns = ['category']
row = data.iloc[:,0]
row = np.array(row)
col = data.iloc[:,1]
col = np.array(col)
wordData = data.iloc[:,2]
wordData = np.array(wordData)
data = sparse.coo_matrix((wordData,(row,col)),shape=(701,2501))
data = data.toarray()
c = pd.DataFrame(data).iloc[1:,1:]
c = c.join(mailLabel)
data = c
data['category'] = data['category'].replace(0,'nospam')
data['category'] = data['category'].replace(1,'spam')

#transfer the test dataset
spam_test = pd.read_csv("emails-test-features.txt",' ',header=None)
row = spam_test.iloc[:,0]
row = np.array(row)
col = spam_test.iloc[:,1]
col = np.array(col)
wordData = spam_test.iloc[:,2]
wordData = np.array(wordData)
spam_test = sparse.coo_matrix((wordData,(row,col)),shape=(701,2501))
spam_test = spam_test.toarray()
d = pd.DataFrame(spam_test).iloc[1:,1:]
spam_test = d
```

### second part code

```
classes=['spam', 'nospam']
# data structure
class Emaildata:
    def __init__(self,c,p,m,s):
        self.classes=c
        self.prior=p
        self.means=m
        self.stdev=s
# training phase
def spamFilterTrain(data,classes):
    means = dict()
    stdev = dict()
    prior = dict()
    for c in classes:
        means[c]=data[data.category==c].mean()
        stdev[c]=data[data.category==c].std()
        prior[c]=len(data[data.category==c])/len(data)
    return Emaildata(classes, prior, means, stdev)
```

### third part code

```
#prediction phase
def spamFilterTest(classifier,x):
logScores = dict()
bestScore = -float(np.inf)
bestClass = classifier.classes[0]
finalScore = np.ones(x.shape[0], dtype=np.float64)
finalClass = list(range(x.shape[0]))
for i in range(x.shape[0]):
    for c in classes:
        logScores[c] = np.log(classifier.prior[c])
        for var in range(x.shape[1]):
            logScores[c] +=  np.log(stats.norm(classifier.means[c][var],classifier.stdev[c][var]).pdf(x.ioc[i,var]))
        if (logScores[c] > 0):
            bestScore = logScores[c]
            bestClass = c
    finalScore[i] = bestScore
    finalClass[i] = bestClass
    return (finalClass,finalScore)
```

### fourth part code

```
mySPAM = spamFilterTrain(data, classes)

spamFilterTest(mySPAM,spam_test)
```

When I run the code `spamFilterTest(mySPAM,spam_test)`, it generates an issue that I don't understand as below.

### issue

```
KeyError                                  
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-b8cb97dbd2a1> in <module>()
----> 1 spamFilterTest(mySPAM,range(3))
      2 #spamFilterTest(mySPAM,spam_test)

<ipython-input-17-db644fe629ee> in spamFilterTest(classifier, x)
     44         #P(s)
     45         for var in range(len(x)):
---> 46             logScores[c] +=              
np.log(stats.norm(classifier.means[c][var],classifier.stdev[c][var]).pdf(x[var]))
     47         if (logScores[c]>0):
     48             bestScore=logScores[c]

/Users/yuanhaoran/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    601         key = com._apply_if_callable(key, self)
    602         try:
--> 603             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    604 
    605             if not is_scalar(result):

/Users/yuanhaoran/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   2167         try:
   2168             return self._engine.get_value(s, k,
-> 2169                                                 
tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
   2170         except KeyError as e1:
   2171             if len(self) > 0 and self.inferred_type in   
                    ['integer', 'boolean']:

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/index.c:3557)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/index.c:3240)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4279)()

pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:13742)()

pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:13696)()

KeyError: 0
```

Comment: the problem at this line. `logScores[c] +=  np.log(stats.norm(classifier.means[c][var],classifier.stdev[c][var]).pdf(x.ioc[i,var]))`. It seems that some library is missing something or cannot find the value of an object you are passing to it. Divide the line in multiple ones so you can locate the error. Print all you get.

Comment: For example print the following lines:
`classifier.means[c][var]`
`classifier.stdev[‌​c][var]`
`x.ioc[i‌​,var]`
and make sure the have correct values.

Comment: @arracso ar first, many thanks for your response, and I change the code as ' logScores[c] += np.log(stats.norm(classifier.means[c].iloc[var],classifier.stdev[‌​c].iloc[var]).pdf(x.ioc[i‌​,var])) ' it works, thank you again !

Comment: glad you find the error